# Trabaja bien esta forma de CRUD con SQL Y C#?

Tags: c#, sql

Necesito saber si esta forma de hacer CRUD mediante SQL Y C# trabaja bien, ya que no se trabajar con procedimiento almacenado. Al mismo tiempo, me gustaría saber como se llama esta forma de hacer CRUD con C# Y SQL.  Quiero comenzar a trabajar con una aplicación, pero necesito de su repuesta.

Esta es la forma que aprendí, pero quiero saber si trabaja bien.

```
public Conexion()
{
    try
    {
        cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Registro;Integrated Security=True");
        cn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se conecto a la base de dato" + ex.ToString());

    }
}


public string insertar(int codigo, string producto, int cantidad, decimal precio, decimal importe)
{
    string salida = "Producto agregado";
    try
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Inventario (Codigo,Producto,Cantidad,Precio,Importe) VALUES (" + codigo + ",  '" + producto + "' , " + cantidad + " , " + precio + " , " +importe+ ")", cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        salida = "No se pudo insertar a la base de dato" + ex.ToString();
    }

    return salida; // Devolviendo un string
}

public int Registrarpersona(int codigo)// Esto sirve para chequear si ya existe un registro
{
    int contador = 0;
    try
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Inventario where Codigo = " + codigo + "", cn);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            contador++;
        }

        dr.Close(); // Cuando leo registros ( SqlDataReader = dr) simpre debo cerrar la Base de Datos
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se pudo llenar" + ex.ToString());
    }
    return contador;
}

//  Llenando un DataGridview 
public void Llenandodatadgridv(DataGridView dgv) // Utilizando el objeto DataGridview como parametro
{
    try
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Inventario", cn); // hacer un isntancia con DataAdater y luego otra de DataTable
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dgv.DataSource = dt;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se pude llenar el datagrid " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No trabaja bien esa forma de programar por las siguiente razones

- no usas parametros, concatener valores en un string no es recomendable
- en los metodos pasas muchos parametros con los datos, cuando deberias definir entidades

Deberias evaluar programar orientado a capas, no digo que sean todas, pero al menos la capa de datos, podria ser aplicando el patron Repository

La idea es que definas una entidad

```
public class Inventario{
  public int codigo {get;set;}
  public string producto {get;set;}
  public int cantidad{get;set;}
  //resto propiedades
}
```

entonces en el repositorio de inventario

```
public class InventarioRepository{

    public void Crear(Inventario entity)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
        { 
            string sql = @"INSERT INTO NombreTabla (codigo, producto, cantidad, ...) 
                            VALUES (@codigo, @producto, @cantidad, ...)"; 
         
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", entity.codigo); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@producto", entity.codigo); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", entity.codigo); 
            //resto
            
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        } 
    }
    
    
}
```